# Find (x,y) solutions to equation

Tags: c, equation

The program receives a positive number `k` from the user and should check how many solutions there are to the equation

```
3*x+5*y=k
```

In case of many solutions the function takes the greater absolute value of `|x-y|` of all solutions. If there is only one solution it prints it. For example:

- If the user types `k=34` there are two solutions for `(x,y)`: `(3,5)` and `(8,2)`. Hence there are two solution the program calculates `|8-2|` and `|3-5|` and takes the greater one, 6.
- If the user for example types `k=8` there is only one solution, `(1,1)`.

Sadly my teacher asked from me to use only loops, `if` and `else` statements. No recursion, no helper functions and no arrays. She also wants the program to be efficient so I cannot use a loop inside a loop.

I tried to write the code but the program does not respond. I defined `counter` to count number of possible solutions for the equation and `distance` the greater absolute value:

```
void check_how_many_solutions(int n) {
    int  y = 0, counter = 0, distance = 0, equation1 = 0, equation2 = 0, equation3 = 0; 
    while (equation3 <= n) {
        equation1 = (n - (5 * y)) / 3;
        equation2 = (n - (3 * equation1)) / 5; 
        equation3 = (3 * equation1) + (5 * equation2);
        if (equation3 == n) { 
            counter++;  
            if (fabs(equation1 - equation2) > distance)
                distance = fabs(equation1 - equation2);
        }
        y++;
    }   
    if (counter > 1)
        printf("The values of x and y are (%d,%d)\n", equation1, equation2); 
    else
        printf("The greater absolute value of |x-y| is %d\n", distance);
}
```

The code does run but with no result.

Comment: The equation 3x + 5y = 35 is just the equation of a straight line, and has an infinite number of (x,y) pairs that satisfy the equation.

Comment: Are you looking only for Integer solutions? Positive integer solutions?

Comment: Ye ole' `y = m(x) + b` rearranged slightly.

Comment: As @FredK pointed out there are more than two solutions. For any value of `k` the solutions are `(2k+5n, -k-3n)` where `n` is any number.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a program I made that I believe answers the question you're asking. You just want to loop through the whole number values of x and check if the computed y is also a whole number. I also keep track of the total number of solutions found and the solution with the greatest distance between x and y, and I give the final answer according to these.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void count_solns(double);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2 && argv[1]) {
        int k = atoi(argv[1]);
        count_solns(k);
    }
    else {
        puts("Usage: count_solns <positive_integer>");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void count_solns(double k)
{
    printf("Print positive integer solutions to 3x + 5y = %.3f\n", k);
    int solns_found = 0;
    int distance = -1;
    int final_x, final_y;
    double x, y;
    for (x = 0; x <= (k/3); x++) {
        y = (k-3*x)/5;
        if (y == floor(y)) {
            printf("Solution found at (x, y) == (%d, %d)\n", (int) x, (int) y);
            solns_found++;
            if (fabs(x-y) > distance) {
                final_x = x;
                final_y = y;
            }
        }
    }
    if (solns_found == 0)
        printf("No whole number solutions found for 3x + 5y = %.3f", k);
    else if (solns_found == 1)
        puts("This is the only solution where x and y are both whole numbers");
    else
        printf("The whole number solution with the highest distance between x and y is (x, y) == (%d, %d)", final_x, final_y);
    return;
}
```

Usage looks like this:

```
$ ./count_solns 70
Print positive integer solutions to 3x + 5y = 70.000
Solution found at (x, y) == (0, 14)
Solution found at (x, y) == (5, 11)
Solution found at (x, y) == (10, 8)
Solution found at (x, y) == (15, 5)
Solution found at (x, y) == (20, 2)
The solution with the highest distance between x and y is (x, y) == (20, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before looking at max1000001's solution I recommend you find where you screwed up first, fix it, and then compare.

Your code currently loops infinitely.  Try going through just a few iterations of your code and print the variables and see if they make sense to you for each iteration.  Here is your same code simplified, the loop limited to 20 iterations, and printing the variables in each iteration:

```
void check_how_many_solutions(int n) {
    int  y = 0, counter = 0, distance = 0, equation1 = 0, equation2 = 0, equation3 = 0; 
    while( y < 20){
    //while (equation3 <= n) {
        equation1 = (n - (5 * y)) / 3;
        equation2 = (n - (3 * equation1)) / 5; 
        equation3 = (3 * equation1) + (5 * equation2);
        printf("y: %i, equation1: %i, equation2: %i, equation3: %i\n",y,equation1,equation2,equation3);
        y++;
    }   
}
```